# Maximum size of a RAID0 on a HP Proliant DL380 with a Smart Array 410i controller?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid0

I've been tasked with buying a server that needs a ton of storage in a RAID0 (in the 8-12TB range). Since I know nothing about RAID controllers, I figured I could just put 4x2TB into a RAID0 array and be on my merry way. (Yes, I know this is a terrible idea from a risk perspective, but the data on this machine will be transient, it just needs to have a ton of storage).

However, looking at the 410i data sheet, it appears that they list the maximum configuration as for SATA disks is a 24x500GB for 12TB. Does this mean that a 4x2TB option won't work? If not, is there any way to put a combination of disks into this machine that will look like a single 8TB drive to the OS?

I apologize if any of these questions are silly, I don't typically spec out servers so I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 4x2TB option should work. You may have to play with GUID partition tables to make all of that presentable as a single 8TB volume, though. A better option in my opinion if you insist on RAID 0 for the dataset, is to create a RAID 1 OS Logical Drive drive of say, 200GB and a second Logical Drive set to RAID 0, comprised of the remaining space. Smart Array controllers allow you mix RAID levels on the same set of drives. At least this will protect your OS setup, even if the data is not important.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You don't happen to know why they put 24x500GB as "maximum" in the datasheet, would you? Was it just written at a time when 500GB was the maximum size of a SATA disk, perhaps?

Comment: Those are recommendations in the Quickspecs located at: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13201_na/13201_na.HTML

Comment: I was just worried that 500GB per disk represented some kind of hardware limit and the controller was unable to handle larger disks.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I see what you mean now about the recommendations. I had not noticed that earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Last time I checked, HP were only shipping 500Gb SATA drives as their maximum drive size in 2.5" form factor. I would guess that is the reason for the specs limit.

Comment: But Seagate Constellation drives are available in 1TB in 2.5" SAS and SATA interfaces. I've used them in certain situations. The new HP part numbers are 605835-B21 for 1TB SAS and 625609-B21 for 1TB SATA.